# SAS reading from a dataset then write to Excel

Tags: sas

Below is the sas code to read some data from a dataset, then write the data to an excel file, however, there is some problem.

```
LIBNAME mck_pred "N:\Data-Dump\test\training" compress=yes;

proc sql;
create table temp as 
select cust_id, number from mck_pred.pred_data;
quit;

proc export data=temp output="C:\Users\test.xlsx" dbms=XLSX replace;
run;
```

the error shows:

```
OTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
2463  proc export  data=temp output="C:\Users\test.xlsx" dbms=XLSX replace;
                                      ------
                                      22
                                      76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, (, DATA, DBLABEL, DBMS, DEBUG, FILE,
              LABEL, OUTFILE, OUTTABLE, REPLACE, TABLE, _DEBUG_.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

2464  run;
```

Regarding the code as shown, I have three problems:

1. what does `compress=yes` mean?
2. How to change the program so that it could run successfully?
3. When should we use `quit` and `run` in the program?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us how that code _does not_ run successfully

Comment: @user2877959 already added the error message

Answer (score 2):

1) `compress=yes` means that new datasets you create in library `mck_pred` will have their observations compressed. In this particular example, it has no impact.

3) To make a long story short, `quit` is used with `proc sql`, `run` is used with `data` steps and all other SAS procedures.

2) The syntax for the output path is `outfile=`, not `output=`. You should also mention `dbms=xlsx` on your `proc export` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and I already tried the dmbs=xlsx, still cannot work, and I already showed the log message. Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: Table WORK.TEMP created, with 190000 rows and 2 columns.

2497  quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           20.35 seconds
      cpu time            20.32 seconds


2498
2499  proc export  data=temp outfile="C:\Users\test.xlsx" replace;
2500  run;

ERROR: Failed to connect to the Server: .
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE EXPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.17 seconds
      cpu time            0.14 second

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't _"still show the error"_. The error you had is gone and it now shows another one. I see also that you again did not specify `dbms=xlsx`. You should.

Comment: Are you using SAS EG? If so you need to export to a location you have access to, which is usually not the C drive.

Comment: when I add "dbms=xlsx", it shows that "DMBS Type XLSX not valid for export", not sure what is the problem with this one.

Comment: @Reeza Yes, I am using SAS EG, but I have access to this folder, and I changed to F drive, similar problem..

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? Submit `%put &sysver;` in EG and check the log if you aren't sure. Do you have SAS/Access Interface to PC Files? Submit `proc setinit;run;` in EG and check the log if you aren't sure. If the latter is true but you are running an older version of SAS, you may have to specify `dbms=excel` or `dbms=xls` instead.

Comment: Post your full code and log. All of it. Make sure you've made the changes already suggested, ie outfile instead of output.